# How to pass Kotlin lambda to Java Supplier argument?

Tags: java, kotlin, migration

I migrate my project to Kotlin and this phase has a lot of interaction between Java and Kotlin.

In sample below I need to pass a function which implements Java Supplier interface.

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.supplyAsync<Int>({ -> 3 }, executor)

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync({ 3 }, executor)
```

IntellJ shows error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Supplier<Int!>!
Found: () -> Int
```

I found a workaround with a helper class but it is not an inline solution.

```
class Help : Supplier<Int> { fun get() = 3 }
supplyAsync(Help(), executor)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will work:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync({ 3 }, executor::execute)
```

Note that the two signatures are

```
public static <U> supplyAsync(supplier: Supplier<U>, executor: Executor): CompletableFuture<U>
public static <U> supplyAsync(supplier: () -> U, executor: (Runnable) -> Unit): CompletableFuture<U>
```

That is, if you want to pass in a lambda, the thing that executes it has to be a method reference (instead of an `Executor` instance).

Edit: This is documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html), Kotlin allows you to call methods that take SAM (functional interface) parameters with proper Kotlin functions as arguments. However, this is all or nothing. Either you pass a Kotlin function for all SAM parameters, or for none. This explains why the approach you originally took didn't compile. This is not specific methods of the Java API, but instead works for all methods defined on Java classes.

Comment: So basically you mean there is an implicit second signature that takes lambdas instead of SAM objects, but there will be no signature that mixes and matches interfaces and lambdas?

Comment: This also works `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier{ 3 }, executor)`, and I think if I'm understanding you correctly, it's because the SAM constructor literally creates an object implementing the interface so it uses the first signature above.

Comment: I liked solution with Supplier{3} more, cause it is calling the method I wanted. Definitely Intellij should take care of this situation with a hint about implicit methods, cause the CompletableFuture is Java class.

Comment: Yes, Kotlin somehow implicitly adds methods that make Java methods accepting functional interfaces usable from Kotlin with lambdas. I don't know of any place where these methods are documented, besides from the auto completion that comes with IntelliJ.